# any software or online service to draw web page layout sketch?

Tags: website-design, web-app, tools

any software or online service to draw web page layout sketch?

I want to construct a website , the first step is that I need to sketch a contents layout for every page . this job can be write done on paper,but not easy to modify and saved.
 and I don't want to use photoshop to do this job ,for it is not easy to select elements and text.photoshop should be used for final design of webpage.

any good advices?

Comment: You want to create wireframes. Search for 'wireframe tools' on this site and you will find plenty of questions pertaining to this.

Comment: I'm going to need @JonW to let me know how this is the kind of question that Q&A forums are good for...

Comment: @Shash This isn't really a "forum". Forums are for discussion, this is a community for specific, answerable questions. If you have a problem with comments on your question, I recommend visiting our meta and asking about it there, where we can help you out. Or visit the chat to talk with us about it. But this is not the right place.

Comment: Sorry, but questions requesting recommendations for books / software / apps / papers etc. would fall into the [shopping request](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) category and aren't really suitable to a Q&A website. The reason for this is that there is no one correct answer, and such recommended items would soon be updated and replaced with newer / better versions making the best answers redundant. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such discussions, they're not really suitable for this main site I'm afraid.

Comment: See also [Quick Slicer](http://quickslicer.sourceforge.io) to sketch out a layout easily and fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good one that is relatively easy to pick up is http://www.balsamiq.com/

If you dont like the look of that one here a good roundup article of some more popular ones. http://webdesignledger.com/tools/13-super-useful-ui-wireframe-tools